# Understanding AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Once an AsyncTask call is finished is the thread deleted?

I stored an AsyncTask in a var "guiThread = (GUIAsyncTask) new GUIAsyncTask()".
The first call to execute() works but subsequent calls don't.
So, do I just create new tasks whenever I need them? I was under the impression that I used my variable over and over and calling new over and over would spin up thousands/millions of threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AsyncTasks` are one-time uses.  They start, execute, then die.  Then you have a choice of keeping the reference around to gather information from it that may be stored in the class post-execute, or dumping the reference and letting the garbage collector handle it.  If you want to start the `AsyncTask` again, you have to create a new object and start it.

Answer (score 1):

Nope you need to create a new AyncTask everytime you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask must be created any time it is to be used